# Exception Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: exception, nosuchelementexception

I have an exception `NoSuchElementException`;

My program itself isn't done but I cant figure out this error I know it is something small 
It has something to do with int inputs.  I am unsure if I am missing something

```
int low= in.nextInt(); 
in.nextLine();
System.out.println(low);
int high= in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
System.out.println(high);
int secretNum= in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
System.out.println(secretNum);
int [] arr= new int [high];
```

Comment: I added a System.out.println(); and it solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thank you 
System.out.println(); after the first 
int low= in.nextInt(); 
All good!